# Google storage item with CORS and cookie-based authentication

Tags: cookies, cors, google-cloud-storage

My reading of [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris#cookieauth) is that if I wanted to make
an in-browser XMLHttpRequest on behalf of a logged-in user, I would need to use a URL of the form:

https://storage.cloud.google.com/BUCKET/OBJECT

Because those URLs respect cookie-based authentication.

However, my testing seems to indicate that the [CORS headers set for the bucket](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) are not sent along with the response from URLs of that form (but they are from URLs of the form storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/OBJECT).

Is this true?  Is there no way to get both cookie-based authentication, and CORS headers?

Comment: Does your request set the Origin header?

Comment: @monsur, I think so.  XMLHttpRequest Level 2 is supposed to send it.  This is in the latest Chrome browser, so Level 2 is supported.  And I get a different error when I enable and disable CORS for the bucket (using the storage.googleapis.com form).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Custom CORS policies are only fully supported via the "storage.googleapis.com" endpoint (including custom domain names with CNAME redirects to c.storage.googleapis.com), and that endpoint does not support cookies. There is not a good way to use both at once.

I would suggest avoiding cookie-based authentication if you can. OAuth 2 is a good alternative and may provide additional benefits, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to do an XMLHttpRequest in the browser for a logged-in user.  How can I use OAuth2 to do that?

Comment: You would use OAuth 2 to get an access_token. That access token would then be passed to the API call either as a query parameter or, preferably, using the Authorization header. There are some instructions here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent and there's a good overview here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#clientside